# Error while creating Taxonomy in Google Data Catalog using Apache Airflow

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, airflow, google-data-catalog

Experts,

I'm trying to create a Taxonomy in Google Data Catalog using Apache Airflow.
When I trigger the job in Airflow, it fails with below error.

**Error**

```
> google.api_core.exceptions.PermissionDenied: 403 The caller does not have permission
rpc._channel._InactiveRpcError: <_InactiveRpcError of RPC that terminated with:
    status = StatusCode.PERMISSION_DENIED
    details = "The caller does not have permission"
    debug_error_string = "{"created":"@1660850910.057899765","description":"Error received from peer ipv4:173.194.216.95:443","file":"src/core/lib/surface/call.cc","file_line":1074,"grpc_message":"The caller does not have permission","grpc_status":7}"
```

although, it states Permission denied, I'm able to create Tagging Templates and tags using Apache Airflow operators.
I'd appreciate if anyone help me figure out and fix the actual issue.

**Code**

```
def sample_create_taxonomy():
    client = datacatalog_v1.PolicyTagManagerClient()
    request = datacatalog_v1.CreateTaxonomyRequest
    (
    parent='projects/sample-project-name/locations/us-central1',
    )
    response = client.create_taxonomy(request=request)
    print(response)
```

Comment: Hi @sabby, Did the answer below help you in resolving the issue?

Comment: yes, it did. I had to check the permissions and those were not granted properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [Data Catalog documentation](https://cloud.google.com/data-catalog/docs/reference/rpc/google.cloud.datacatalog.v1#google.cloud.datacatalog.v1.CreateTaxonomyRequest) you need to have `datacatalog.taxonomies.create` IAM permission on `projects/sample-project-name/locations/us-central1`.